# how to set std code as prefix in phone number?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new for iOS. In my app I need to add phone number. I adding the phone number in my profile `for e.g. 1234567890` and when I am on display page then it show same 1234567890 but i want it shoe with std code as prefix `for eg (for India)+911234567890`.

can any one help me for this.
Thanks.

Comment: if your app is use only in india or else

Comment: it is for india only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *stdCode = @"+91";
NSString *phoneNumber = @"1234567890";
NSString *resultStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", stdCode, phoneNumber];
```